# Difference between np.random.seed(1) and np.random.seed(0)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, artificial-intelligence

I am looking an networks. I find this topic https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/

Its going good but i cant understand that part:

```
# seed random numbers to make calculation
# deterministic (just a good practice)

np.random.seed(1)

# initialize weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1
```

so whats the mean that `np.random.seed(1)`? why it isnt (0)? whats the mean of (1))
and page writer says "initialize weights randomly with mean 0" for

```
syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1
```

what does it mean for ann weights?

Comment: It seems odd to seed the random number generator at all.  Seeding it will cause the same sequence of "random" numbers every time you run the program. The "with mean 0" means that it's going to return values between -1 and 1.  If evenly distributed, the mean will be 0.

Comment: how can it return between -1 and 1 with multiply "2" and extract "1" ????

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Python random function, so I'm guessing it returns a number floating point number between 0 and 1.  If you double that, you get between 0 and 2.  Subtract 1 and it's -1 to 1.  I don't know what the list argument is though, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @Alper Kutlu : In this case, a random number x given by np.random is between 0 and 1. Now, in order to get a random number between -1 and 1, you can use an easy math trick:   let a = -1 and b = 1. Since a < b --> (b-a) > 0. And so the inequality 0 <= x <= 1 is equivalent to 0 <= (b-a)x <= (b-a). Now by adding the value a to the inequality, we get: a <= a + (b-a)x <= b which is equivalent to -1 <= 2x-1 <= 1. In other words, you can be guaranteed to have a random number between -1 and 1 if you start with a random number between 0 and 1 and then you multiply "2" and extract "1" .

Answer (score 4):

**Question #1:**

For practical purposes, there is no difference, it's just a way to get the same random numbers each time you run your programm. Feel free to read more details on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

**Question #2:**

Initializing your ANN with zero-mean weights is a good practice that often shows good convergence behavior. Check out this page for more details: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init

> Therefore, we still want the weights to be very close to zero, but as
>   we have argued above, not identically zero. As a solution, it is
>   common to initialize the weights of the neurons to small numbers and
>   refer to doing so as symmetry breaking. The idea is that the neurons
>   are all random and unique in the beginning, so they will compute
>   distinct updates and integrate themselves as diverse parts of the full
>   network.

There's more discussion on that topic in a Quora thread: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-it-work-to-initialize-weights-of-a-deep-Neural-Network-to-zero-plus-some-noise-N-0-epsilon-and-not-anything-else

Comment: thanks for answer but i still have a question for 2nd:

syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1

why we multiply with "2" and why we extract "1" for mean of that?
i cant understand 2 and 1 values

Comment: @AlperKutlu To make it centered / mean=0. You can also do 1 * random - 0.5. But tha's more ugly. Read up what random.random returns if you don't know it.